# Mounting windows server 2016 Azure VM GPT basic NTFS partition on linux

Tags: mount, ntfs, gpt

I have an azure blob (a .vhd disk) which is a copy of a windows data disk created by taking a snapshot of the live disk, then copying that snapshot to a temporary blob, which is the blob I have attached to my Linux box.

In windows, the disk is a Basic disk, with a 200GB partition labelled SQLVMDATA1, rest is unallocated.

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          127 GB    66 GB
  Disk 1    Online           16 GB      0 B
  Disk 3    Online         1022 GB   821 GB        *

DISKPART> select disk 3

Disk 3 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Reserved           128 MB    17 KB
  Partition 2    Primary            200 GB   129 MB
```

When attached to linux (CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810) it appears as /dev/sdc (sdc1 scd2)

```
(parted) print                                                            
Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1098GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  134MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   1098GB  1098GB               SQLVMStoragePool1
```

Firstly, these partitions don't match the partitions as listed in windows.

Any attempt to mount partition 2 reports

```
[root@rsa-oz1 boot]# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc2 /mnt/disk
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

blkid reports

```
[root@rsa-oz1 boot]# blkid /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc: PTTYPE="gpt" 
[root@rsa-oz1 boot]# blkid /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="a82bce67-815b-11e9-a815-002248005d03" 
[root@rsa-oz1 boot]# blkid /dev/sdc2
/dev/sdc2: PARTLABEL="SQLVMStoragePool1" PARTUUID="a82bce68-815b-11e9-a815-002248005d03"
```

I presume that windows is sub-partitioning /dev/sdc2 question is how do I mount those on Linux?

Comment: The million dollar question is how was that "blob" created?

Comment: Specifically? 
Start-AzStorageBlobCopy with the source being a snapshot of a .vhd created with Get-AzStorageBlob and $blob.ICloudStorage.CreateSnapshot()
Basically, it's a copy of a .vhd disk.